# Finding the equation of the curve that passes through the point $(4,3)$ if its slope is given by $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x-5$

Tags: calculus

I tried substituting the $4$ into the $3x-5$ equation, so my slope would be represented as $3(4)-5 = 7$. Then my equation for the line would be $y-3 = 7(x-4)$. That means the equation of the line would be $y = 7x - 25$. However, I'm trying to submit this answer online and it comes back as incorrect. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You have the slope is $7$ at the point $(4,3)$ which is correct. But, what you found was the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(4,3)$.

**SOLUTION:** We need to integrate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to get the function of the original curve. So,
$$y=\int (3x-5) \ dx=\frac{3}{2}x^2-5x+C.$$

Now, we plug in the point $(4,3)$ to find $C$.
$$3=\frac{3}{2}(4^2)-5(4)+C.$$

So, $C=-1$ and $$y=\frac{3}{2}x^2-5x-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation only satisfies $y'(x) = 3x-5$ at the point $(4,3)$, rather than everywhere.  You need to take the antiderivative to get the family of curves $y = (3/2)x^2 - 5x + C$ that satisfy the given differential equation everywhere.  Solve for $C$ by plugging in $(4,3)$ to this family, instead.